# Отправка файла на сервер после удаления формы из DOM

Tags: javascript, ajax, файлы, dom

столкнулся с проблемой отправки файла на сервер после того как форма удалена из DOM.

Мой скрипт отправки данных работает следующим образом:

1. при наступлении события 'input'  на любом поле ввода формы данные поля записываются в объект, который в последствии передаётся на сервер.
2. далее при нажатии кнопки отправки данных вызывается метод отправки данных, а сама форма удаляется методом Node.remove().

Это работает со всеми полями ввода, кроме `<input type=file/>`.

Псевдо-код для понимания процесса:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="my_form">
  <input type="file" name="file"/>
  <input type="text" name="title"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>

<script>
let obj = { //объект для отправки на сервер
  'form_data':{}, //данные формы
  'tmpl_data':{...}, //какие-то другие данные
};

let backend = new Backend(obj, ...); //объект, отправляющий данные на сервер

//добавить в obj данные поля file
document.body.querySelector('input[type=file]').addEventListener('input', function(){
  obj[event.target.name] = event.target;
});

//добавить в obj данные поля text
document.body.querySelector('input[type=text]').addEventListener('input', function(){
  obj[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
});

document.body.querySelector('input[type=submit]').addEventListener('input', function(){
  backend.query(); //отправка данных на сервер
  my_form.remove(); //удаление формы
});
</script>
```

Данные полей формы полученные как event.target.value записывают в объект данных obj для сервера "примитивные данные", которые не являются ссылками. С другой стороны информация из input type=file это объект. Т.к. отправка данных происходит ассинхронно, то форма удаляется из DOM до того как была произведена отправка данных на сервер. При этом в консоли я получаю предупреждение: "Form submission canceled because the form is not connected" и отправка данных не происходит.

Я пробовал клонировать объект полученный из поля file, не помогло.

Использование FormData мне не подходит. Также необходимо сохранить логику работы формы, теоретически можно ждать ответа сервера и после этого удалять форму из DOM, но в данном случае такой подход не годится.

Есть ли способ обойти это поведение и отправить данные из поля file на сервер после удаления формы из DOM? Т.е. мне необходимо, чтобы после удаления формы из DOM данные файлового поля были доступны.

Дополнено:

Если форма не удаляется из DOM, то сервер получает примерно такой массив данных:

```
Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [test] => lamp.png
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [test] => image/png
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [test] => Z:\tmp\php9ECA.tmp
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [test] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [test] => 48141
                )

        )
```

Реализовать тоже самое если форма удалена из DOM не получается.
Да, можно сохранить ссылку используя псевдо-массив files, и получить из него имя файла, MIME, и размер, но невозможно передать серверу адрес временного хранения файла (в данном случае: Z:\tmp\php9ECA.tmp)

Для отправки данных на сервер я использую старую, но проверенную годами библиотеку JsHttpRequest. Если вставить в DOM просто одно поле ввода файла:

```
<body>
<input type="file" name="any_file"/>
</body>
```

и попробовать отправить данные из него на сервер, то я получаю такую ошибку:

> Ошибка: JsHttpRequest: не удается найти загрузчик, который может обработать запрос. Примечания: - XML: невозможно использовать загрузчик XMLHttpRequest: прямое использование элементов формы и загрузка не реализованы - SCRIPT: невозможно использовать загрузчик SCRIPT: прямое использование элементов формы и загрузка не реализованы - FORM: элемент «any_file» не принадлежит ни к какой форме !

Т.е. здесь ключевым моментом является то, что элемент не принадлежит ни к какой форме. И это надо как-то обойти...

Comment: Да можете так сделать с использованием Blob. Но, зачем вам это? Зачем такие сложности? В чем смысл? Вы знаете, иногда автокомплит с браузера не вызывает событие `input`, также некоторые клавиатуры на мобильном не вызывают событие `input`.

Comment: Какое событие будет срабатывать при взаимодействии с формой в данном случае носит второстепенный характер. Можно использовать и событие 'change' или что-то подобное... дело не в этом. Можно посмотреть пример с BLOB?

Answer (score 0):

Можно сохранять ссылку не на дом элемент, а на список файлов.

```js
let obj = { //объект для отправки на сервер
};
//добавить в obj данные поля file
document.body.querySelector('input[type=file]').addEventListener('input', function() {
  obj[event.target.name] = event.target.files;
});

//добавить в obj данные поля text
document.body.querySelector('input[type=text]').addEventListener('input', function() {
  obj[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
});

document.body.querySelector('input[type=submit]').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  document.body.querySelector('#my_form').remove();
  console.log(obj);
  event.preventDefault();
  // проверка, что действительно файл доступен после удаления формы.
  setTimeout(() => {
    readFile(obj.file[0]);
  }, 500);
});

function readFile(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    // The file's text will be printed here
    console.log(e.target.result)
  };

  reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="my_form">
  <input type="file" name="file" />
  <input type="text" name="title" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```